# How to get the value of a variable defined in tf.name_scope()?

Tags: tensorflow

```
with tf.name_scope('hidden4'):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(weights4))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(biases4))
    hidden4 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden3, weights) + biases)
```

I want to ues tf.get_variable to get the variable hidden4/weights defined as above, but failed as below:

```
hidden4weights = tf.get_variable("hidden4/weights:0")
*** ValueError: Variable hidden4/weights:0 already exists, disallowed.       Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 234, in default
exec code in globals, locals
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 220, in onecmd
return self.default(line)
```

Then I try hidden4/weights.eval (sess), but it also failed.

```
(Pdb) hidden4/weights.eval(sess)
*** NameError: name 'hidden4' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tf.name_scope()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#name_scope) is used to visualize variables.

> tf.name_scope(name)
>
> - Wrapper for Graph.name_scope() using the default graph.

What I think you are looking for is [tf.variable_scope()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html):

> Variable Scope mechanism in TensorFlow consists of 2 main functions:
>
> - tf.get_variable(, , ): Creates or returns a variable with a given name.
> - tf.variable_scope(): Manages namespaces for names passed to tf.get_variable().

```
with tf.variable_scope('hidden4'):
    # No variable in this scope with name exists, so it creates the variable
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", <shape>, tf.convert_to_tensor(weights4)) # Shape of a new variable (hidden4/weights) must be fully defined
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", <shape>, tf.convert_to_tensor(biases4)) # Shape of a new variable (hidden4/biases) must be fully defined
    hidden4 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden3, weights) + biases)

with tf.variable_scope('hidden4', reuse=True):
    hidden4weights = tf.get_variable("weights")

assert weights == hidden4weights
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and detailed description !!  I meet a new problem as below T_T

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem above:

```py
classifyerlayer_W=[v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name == "softmax_linear/weights:0"][0]  #find the variable by name "softmax_linear/weights:0"
init= numpy.random.randn(2048, 4382) # create a array you use to re-initial the variable
assign_op = classifyerlayer_W.assign(init) # create a assign operation 
sess.run(assign_op) # run op to finish the assign
```